# PostgreSQL: Why are quotation marks required in queries when referring to tables and attributes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been learning SQL and haven't been taught to use double quotation marks around table and attribute references in a query, yet I'm using PostgreSQL and it seems to demand this.

It says the relation doesn't exist otherwise when I try to execute a query.

Why is this? Is there a way to change it? I'm using version 9.4.

Comment: It only demands if the table and attribute references you are typing are reserved words.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 3):

The reason is postgres is case sensitive.

So if you **declare** a field / table `"MyField"` but call it `MyField` wouldnt work

because `MyField == myfield`

But if you **declare** your field `myfield`  then that would work and that doesnt require double quotes.

I usually declare all my table names and field in lowercase to avoid using double quoutes.

and instead of `"TableID"` or `"LastName"` I use `table_id` and `last_name`